# Apps not getting downloaded

Tags: updates

When I am installing my apps from Playstore its not getting installed and the previous apps which are already installed or not getting updated I brought a new mobile from a store recently but I am facing this issue:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try to reset your Google Play Store and then try to download it....

Comment: Disconnect from Wifi then reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Check your network speed, 4g is better option, many times it is observed that on low data connection playstore makes trouble to download apps... 
I can help further if you have mentioned your device name and model

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of these problems

- Slow Internet connection 
  -**it's seems unlikely, you have 4G connection **
- Cache of Google playstore
- **remove cache and data from Google playstore **